# ajuda para otimizar script

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante e escrevi esse código hoje para um exercício de um curso.
O exercício me pede para desenvolver um sistema que filtre as notas de um vestibular e entregue a quantidade de pessoas que vão ingressar na instituição sem ultrapassar o limite de vagas.
O código funciona porem não está 100%, e eu não sei como melhorar ele. Quem puder ajudar eu agradeço.

```js
function solucao(notaMinima,totalDeVagas,notasDoVestibular) {
  var totalDeAprovados = 0;
  
    notasDoVestibular = notasDoVestibular.filter(item => item > notaMinima);
    notasDoVestibular.sort(function(a, b){
      return b - a;
    });
    
    for (const num of notasDoVestibular){
      totalDeAprovados = totalDeAprovados + 1;
    }if (totalDeAprovados > totalDeVagas){
      console.log(totalDeVagas);
    }else {
      console.log(totalDeAprovados);
    }
}

solucao(65,15,[30, 56, 43, 23, 56, 78, 98, 76, 98, 88, 77, 34.5, 67.8, 90.5, 76.8, 94.2, 25.6, 73, 26, 33]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Pode utilizar o método [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) para delimitar o limite de elementos de um Array. Além disso, a propriedade [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) indica a quantidade de elementos nele, sem precisar iterar sobre todos eles em um loop.

`aprovados` representa em ordem decrescente aqueles com notas aceitas.

```js
function solucao(notaMinima, totalDeVagas, notasDoVestibular) {      
    const notasAprovadas = notasDoVestibular.filter(item => item > notaMinima).sort((a, b) => b - a);
    const aprovados = notasAprovadas.slice(0, totalDeVagas);
    console.log(aprovados.length);
}
```

Lembrando que o método `slice` realiza uma cópia superficial. O array inteiro ainda existirá na memória após sua repartição.